# How to encode video packet using video/avc encoder in android live streaming?

Tags: udp, h.264

How to encode raw video packet into RTCP and RTP packet from android camera live streaming using video/avc encoder and send those packet to another device using UDP socket?

Answer (score 0):

The libstreaming open-source library sounds like the right option for you: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

Good luck!